# How console log in terminal every request using node-dev?

Tags: node.js, express, node-dev

How would I go about logging (kind of like tail -f) every request using node-dev so that I am able to see which route is being hit, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using Express.js, I have learned using `app.use(express.logger());` accomplishes what I am looking for.